# Dynamically add features to map in ArcGIS Pro 2.7

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I am trying to dynamically add the contents of a feature dataset to a map in Pro v 2.7.

To achieve this, my understanding of the workflow is that I need to list the features in the feature dataset ('ResultsPath' in code snippet below), then convert to layer, save as a layer file, then add layer. The code below runs without errors, but nothing happens--nothing is added to the map and no layer files are generated. I would try addDataFromPath, but since the lyrx is not generating in the save to layer file process I am stuck for the moment. Any pointers?

```py
#Lists the feature classes in the Results Feature Dataset

#Dynamically convert to layer and add to map.

#Code working, but nothing happening? 

        m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(ResultsPath):
            OutFile = ScratchWS + os.sep + str(fc)
            lf = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, OutFile, None, None).getOutput(0)
            lyf = arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(lf, OutFile)
            m.addLayer(lyf, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

Update: Problem solved, ListFeatureClasses was not referencing the feature dataset properly so was generating an empty list so nothing was happening. The updated code below does list the contents of the feature dataset.

```
    #Lists features from Results feature dataset
    #Makes feature layer from features, adds feature layers to map

    m = aprx.listMaps()[0]
    datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
    for ds in datasets:
        ResultList= arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", ds)
        for fc in ResultList:
            OutFile = os.path.join(wkspc, str(fc))
            lf = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc, None, None)
```

Comment: Your layer name is too long, Make feature layer 2nd parameter is the layer name which is the full path in this case and contains bad characters : and \, try **lf = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, fc)** instead to name the new layer the same as the feature class; when joining paths consider using *os.path.join* instead of simple concatenation. You don't need to save the layer file, skip that and add lf from the make feature layer.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I just tried that out--the code ran, but again did not add the layers to the map.  Any other suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Please update your code. Are you running this in a python console? if so then use print (fc) in your loop to make sure the iterations are occurring, if not then the problem is probably earlier in your script.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelStimson-- when I printed fc, it was an empty list which let me know I was not actually listing the contents of the feature dataset. Problem solved; updated code above.